# Resource Dictionary error in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to do Sqlite database connectivity in Windows Phone Application and after adding necessary dll's and NuGet packages I was getting error as "The type 'ResourceDictionary' is inside a ResourceDictionary and does not exist in the current context". Have I done any mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a key name for the dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="myKey">
```

Move everything to within your MergedDictionary.

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="myKey">      
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
             <localization:LocalizedStrings xmlns:loca;="clr-namespace:Jogger" x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
             <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: thank u. I've set the key as u said. Now it's showing error as "The type 'ResourceDictionary' is inside a ResourceDictionary and does not have a key."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do with ResourceDictionary but the problem can be solved by adding the Key. Please see below lines

```
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="ResourceDictionaryKey">
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: ah, @madhukumar no need to do such formalities, its our work to answer.